# Change the home directory default location in Android Studio

Tags: android, path

I figured out how to change the default *save* location/workspace by creating a new project and picking a different directory.
Before, it was C:\Users\Name\AndroidStudioProjects but now I changed the default *save* location to C:\Name\Android\AndroidStudioProjects

However, in Android Studio **when I go to File > Open it opens to a default directory** of C:\Users\Name\ where it used to be. The sdk is here too so maybe that's why. This is known as the Home Directory in Android Studio, but **how do I change this path?**

Comment: Do you mean your project is reopening to that path? Try going to file > close project, then open it again with the new path.

Comment: I mean that when i click file, then i click open, a pop up comes up to browse my files/folders. The default selected directory however is C:\Users\Name\ and i want to change that to C:\Name\AndroidStudioProjects so i can just open new projects in one click without having to change directories because my AndroidStudioProjects folder isn't in the directory already opened by default

Comment: on Windows, it looks like it uses %USERPROFILE% as the home directory

Comment: Use "Junction Link Magic" and create symlink

Comment: So hard to believe... It’s been impossible to reassign home directory for so many years...

Comment: IDE developers do not develop projects?

Answer (score 12):

[image]

When we want to open a existing project or anything in Android Studio, this window pops up. The four buttons for path variables on top left of the window is used to help navigating to most frequently used directories as **Home Directory**, **Desktop Directory**, **Project Directory** and **Module Directory**. The first two are inherited from system variables and the last two are retrieved from current project settings (that's why they're inactive when no project is opened).

What Jason need as I do either is just a project repository. I use `D:\Workspace\AndroidStudio\` as my project repository storing all my project files. So it's rather inconvenient to navigate to my projects, I have to left click at least 5 times to my repository.

Android Studio doesn't allow users to specify a repository directory and even if it supports user-defined path variables, I can't figure out how to use it in this window. I guess we have to add a button to quickly navigate to repo directory and that's probably too trivial for IDE developers.

Finally, I discovered the **Recent Files** button which can largely help me navigating although not perfectly. I suggest you use this sub-optimal solution instead if you're suffering from mouse-clicking pain like me.

Comment: IDE developers do not develop projects?

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij/Android Studio, the project itself stores the directory of it's own location. In Eclipse, the IDE itself stores the directory of the projects.

I made a list comparing how Android Studio and Eclipse views workspaces and projects here= [Change default save location of projects (or Workspace ) in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012638/change-default-save-location-of-projects-or-workspace-in-android-studio/34664537#34664537)

I think you basically have to move each project or copy and paste all your projects somewhere else. This link might be helpful= 
[How to move and rename a project in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490734/how-to-move-and-rename-a-project-in-android-studio)