# How can I change the default directory of the terminal?

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, adb

I want to change the default directory of the Android Studio (v2.2.2) terminal.

When i open the terminal it is based on the direcetory of the project.

> C:\path-of-the-project\

I often have to use `adb shell`, so i must navigate to the SDK path (platform-tools) to use adb command.

Is it possible to change the default directory of the terminal making it point to the SDK-->tools folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the default directory of the Android Studio terminal.
Go to File->Settings->Tools->Terminal and select the path you want to choose.

[image: Changing terminal path]

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine - Please accept this answer if your query is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to open a existing project or anything in Android Studio, this window pops up. The four buttons for path variables on top left of the window is used to help navigating to most frequently used directories as Home Directory, Desktop Directory, Project Directory and Module Directory. The first two are inherited from system variables and the last two are retrieved from current project settings (that's why they're inactive when no project is opened).
Here is the answer [Change the home directory default location in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819681/change-the-home-directory-default-location-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Example for Android Studio (Windows)

> File/Settings/Tools/Terminal  then:
>       (a) Set Start Directory to your SDK (e.g. C:\@AS_2.2.2_SDK\platform-tools)
>       (b) Set Shell path to cmd.exe (just let it default)

When you refresh the terminal session you will be switched to the Start Directory.
Now you are ready to use **adb** - e.g. type '**adb devices**'

[You no longer have to manually type the '**cd**' command]