# Android Studio - How to edit terminal startup location?

Tags: android, terminal

The current startup location for my terminal is:

```
C:\Users\[name]\Code\[app-dir]\[app-ext]>
```

I want to change it to:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Because now i have to manually type in:

```
cd C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

To get to the directory of adb.exe

I could not find the answer to this question on this forum, neither on google.
I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014583/7654070
This got me a broken terminal. It didnt want to open anymore, so i changed it back to:

```
cmd.exe
```

Any of you know how to do this?

Comment: Add `adb.exe` to `PATH` environment variable any you would be able to use it from any location.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bat file somewhere with contents:

```
@cd /d %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Then in Android Studio Settings/Tools/Terminal replace "Shell path"

```
cmd.exe
```

with

```
"cmd.exe" /K C:\yourbatfile.bat
```

Adding platform-tools folder to path is probaly still a good idea.

Comment: With this command i am getting the error of : "Cannot create PTY"

Comment: Indeed. Sry I did not check. It turns out this method (no longer) works. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the newer versions of Android Studio ,follow these steps:-

1. From the File menu , Select Settings option.
2. Under the tools option, select Terminal and change the start directory to

   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools .
3. Click Ok.
4. Again from the file menu select Invalidate Chahes/Restart ,again restart.

This method would update the current projects terminal default directory .

Comment: This suggestion cannot be correct, it causes local terminal to be unattainable! reinsert cmd.exe if you like me got into trouble. Now local terminal will work again