# How to set Project Directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio-3.0

After clicking "Open an existing Android Studio project", a dialog pops up that shows the directory tree, and buttons on top.  The third button is "Project Directory" (Ctrl+2), which starts grayed-out, and presumably it is there so you can set a designated directory so you can open existing projects faster.  How to set it?

Searching "Project Directory" in the IDE settings gives several irrelevant results.  Pressing a "?" button on the dialog leads to a 404 page.  Googling also gives no results.  Does somebody here know enable this feature?

(Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.)

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently no easy way to set a designated directory to that button. As stated in this question: [Change the home directory default location in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819681/change-the-home-directory-default-location-in-android-studio), first pair of buttons (Home Directory and Desktop Directory) are inherited from system variables. Second pair (Project Directory and Module Directory) is depended on current open projects.

You can see the "Project Directory" button active if you'll try to open a new project while you still have some other project opened.

I guess, it can be done relatively easy with building your own Android Studio from sources, but it may turn into a lot of work later, since you'll need to repeat the process for every new version.

I personally, just press second button Desktop Directory and hover few lines above Desktop folder to my AndroidStudioProjects folder - it saves me a few moves.