# Application Installation Failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk

Yesterday my app was running perfect from `Android Studio` but today when I started working on my app and running it i am getting error message continuously

> Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.

Screen :

[image]

On click **OK** getting error message

> Session 'app':Error Installing APKs

And App is not exist(already Uninstalled) in device. Please suggest me what to do ?

Comment: can you checking in other devices?still that same issue

Comment: yes i was testing on 2 devices today app is running on one device only and getting error by running on another device

Comment: The problem could be the 1) Installed application is higher version compare to the installing one
2)The signature mismatch

Comment: can you post your build gradle?

Comment: Kapil Rajput i am also suffering this problem after update Android studio 2.2 to 2.3

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar i didn't  change version of app till now

Comment: What I did is, Find the app in settings -> Apps -> "App_Name" in that screen at the menu there is an option "Uninstall for all users" . . 
Then try to run it from Stuio

Comment: use adb command to uninstall app

Comment: Are you trying to install into a vitual device or into your phone?

Comment: @Nazimch on my phone from USB debugging

Comment: have you tried to install it on any virtual device?

Comment: @Nazimch No not yet

Comment: try it once may be ok

Comment: This worked for me after a lot of research.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42226014/6749161

Comment: This worked for me after a lot of research in android studio.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42226014/6749161)

Comment: @Kapil Rajput, check my solution because it works ;) - since I posted it quite some people started copying it

Comment: now i hate Android studio most in the world...Ohhh...missing those good days with Eclipse

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Again in this issue also I found Instant Run buggy. When I disable the Instant run and run the app again App starts successfully installing in the Device without showing any error Window. 
I hope google will sort out these Issues with Instant run soon.

Steps to disable Instant Run from Android Studio:

> **File** > **Settings** > **Build,Execution,Deployment** > **Instant Run** > **Un-check**
>   **(Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)**

Comment: It is also work on MIUI ROM without disable MIUI Optimization, When disable MIUI Optimization then few permission auto grant to application like Windowmanager permission

Comment: This fixed the same issue I'm having, but with a Samsung phone!

Comment: more than a year later this still happens.

Comment: Funny (not really). My worthless crap Android Studio (v3.1.2) wouldn't run with Instant Run off.

Comment: For Mac, Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Comment: For Mac, it may be related to lack of space in the device. After disabling instant run I noticed the following message in the Debug tab: Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
The Mac Android transfer application used to transfer files from the device wouldn't be able to connect either.

Comment: Is disabling Instant run a real solution though? It is very useful.

Comment: Another year on, and its still happening.

Comment: Android Studio 3.5 (upgraded from 3.3) still has the bug, but not the control.  Below File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment there are these choices: Gradle, Debugger, Remote Jar Repositories, Compiler, Coverage, Deployment, Espresso Test Recorder, Required Plugins.  No option to control Instant Run!

Answer (score 111):

**If you use MIUI ROM**

Go to the developer option and in that disable MIUI optimization.You will be asked to reboot your phone.
Reboot it and then run the app.

Comment: hope miui guys will fix this soon

Comment: this helped me. MIUI

Comment: I have samsung S7 , I am unable to see MIUI option in developer option can someon please help?

Comment: MIUI option is available for Xioami phones only

Comment: That's the solution, which i was missing from years, thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 51):

Your `APK` file is missing . So , **Clean Project** `>>` **Build APK** `>>` **Run** the project .

Comment: Work for me 
 Clean Project >> Rebuild Project >> Build APK >> Run

Comment: You can Skip "Build APK"

Comment: unfortunately, a Clean didn't fix it for me. I have Instant Run turned off too.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere "apk missing" and "build apk" are the key terms here, "clean project" is for a safe shot

Comment: the problem was that the emulator didn't have enough storage and Android Studio, as hard as it tries to please, only stated "Installation Failed"

Answer (score 31):

For those who uses Xiaomi phones, follow these steps:

1. Settings-> Additional Settings-> Developer options
2. Turn off MIUI Optimization and reboot your phone
3. Last Disable verify app over USB

Your device will respond properly.

Also enable install via USB

Comment: Thanks :). Mark this as solution

Comment: Great, that did it for me. I have then re-enabled "Verify over USB" and it still works, at least for now.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue in Android studio 2.3 when I tried to test the app using Xiaomi's Mi5 and Mi4 phones. Disabling instant run didn't help me. So here is what I did.

```
Turn Off MIUI optimization in the Developer Options in the phone.
```

[image]

[image]

Then the device will be rebooted and then you'll be able to test the app over the phone.

Using this method you can still use **instant run option** in android studio. So this will fix your problem at least temporary. Hope that we'll be able to use MIUI optimization in the near future updates :)

Answer (score 20):

In my case, it was because my emulator ran out of disk space.

Comment: same here. I edited the emulator settings to add more memory: TOOLS -> AVD MANAGER -> EDIT (pen image) -> SHOW ADVANCED SETTINGS -> increase INTERNAL STORAGE

Comment: In my case was my device without space. After delete some apps all worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to restart te emulator after increasing the internal storage.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it was very a silly and funny mistake. I, accidentally without actually knowing, checked "Android Debug Bridge, Use libUsb backend". Actually it should stay unchecked..

In Mac Pro, Go Preferences - > Build, Execution,Deployment -> Debugger.[image]

Comment: Why does this ocurr?

Answer (score 10):

**** **For MAC OSX/Windows** ****

Goto *

> Android Studio - Preferences (In OSX)
>
> Android Studio - File -> Settings (In Windows)

- in the menu bar then select

> Build,Execution,Deployment - Instant run

- then uncheck it and rebuild it will works

Answer (score 9):

**Finally I've SOLVED it!**

Below a **temporary solution**. Issue was reported to Google.

First of all I found in Run log that Android Studion 2.3 tries to install app-debug.apk from many slices, like this:

> $ adb install-multiple -r
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
>   E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Then I tried to install only `app-debug.apk` from command line by:

> **adb install -d E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk**

App was installed successfully but was failed to run on my phone.

And finally:

1. I recompiled `app-debug.apk` from command line as:

> **gradlew.bat assembleDebug**

2. Repeat installation of `app-debug.apk` from command line and became happy:

> **adb install -rd E:\Android_Projects\ActivityLifecycle\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk**

This is definitely some `gradle` problem in `AndroidStudio 2.3`.

Comment: +1. My multidex apk generated from Android Studio 2.3.3 crashed on launch when the apk was installed via adb command line. Re-assembling the apk from command line Gradle solved the issue!

Answer (score 9):

Go to Build --> Clean Project --> Run

Thats all it takes.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in MIUI. Enabling OEM unlocking worked for me without disabling MIUI optimization.

Below is a screenshot of my Redmi 3s prime developer options setting:

[image: screenshot of my Redmi 3s prime developer options setting]

Answer (score 6):

In my own case, it was because *my phone was out of space*. For people that are facing this problem right now, if **Clean Project** + **Build APKs** does not work, check the available space on your phone or emulator.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: This didn't help with my problem caused by renaming the AppName globally

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution go to

```
settings>build,execute,deployment>instant run>Enable instant run to hot swap code /resource change on deploy(unchecked this option)
```

This will work on 3.4 android studio too. thanks

Comment: Once this is done, make sure to check that you've enabled 'install via USB' option in developer options. Did the work for me

Answer (score 4):

Change your `applicationId` in the `android/app/build.gradle` file.

For example:

```
// Change this
applicationId "com.example.myAndroidApp"
//
// to this
applicationId "com.example.somethingElse"
```

Then Sync your gradle then you can able to install your app,
if the previous applicationId is your production id the again change it the previous one now the device will allow to install the app.

Hope this may help you....

Comment: I've tried your method and it works! I have the original app installed in my phone which is deployed by an old computer, then I move to a new computer and copy the source code to it and try to deploy it again, but failed. Maybe it is due to different version of android studio, or gradle, etc. I've been doing all kinds of funny stuffs in order to make the project works but failed. Android Studio told me to uninstall the app on the phone before deploying, I pressed OK but it said failed to install. Then I tried your method and it works!

Comment: I think it is somehow due to the original not really being uninstalled, I still can't figure out why, but at least I am back on track now

Comment: Helped. Thank you!

Comment: After returning to the original app id the problem is here again. I've switched off Instant Run, and it works.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.4 Canary 8. This didn't help my case

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling the Instant run in Settings.

Comment: I am getting the same issue and I disabled instant run but then I get this error message.  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzru;

Answer (score 4):

**Easily can be solved this problem.**

Ex:- in Huawei GR3 mobile,

**Goto Setting in your mobile -> Storage -> Storage Cleaner**

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by "instant run" feature, you can disable it by:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run and u are ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

At me such error arose after renaming of a folder with the project.

Disabling **Instance Run** helped, but what if you do not need to disable it?

I deleted all the tags mentioning the old folder name from the file **myproject\app\build\intermediates\restart-dex\debug\build-info.xml**

The error has disappeared.

Comment: Disabling Instance Run fixed the issue for me. :)

Comment: I deleted some more folders and that worked, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56202359/1069083

Answer (score 3):

> Just do the following step...

Build>Clean Project

after that Run project again, this worked for me

Comment: This didn't help with my problem caused by renaming the AppName globally

Answer (score 3):

I also had the problem after globally changing the project name, applicationid  and the folders containing the java files.

Disabling Instant run helped, but was not a good option, so this helped:

- close Android Studio
- deleted those files and folders: `rm -Rf .gradle .tags local.properties .idea/workspace.xml .idea/caches/* .idea/libraries app/build`
- start Android Studio and let it resync everything
- press run

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issues on MIUI phone resolved by making MIUI account and enable install by USB.

Comment: **Install by USB** is enabled

Answer (score 2):

just close your emulator and run again the problem will be solved happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Sometime app doesn't show on home screen,So
Check your apps by going to setting - > apps ->  and then uninstall from app setting might this work.

Comment: app not exist in apps too :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (there's no need to deactivate instant run) Do all these steps in the stated order:

1- Gradle Build (root level)

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWPeu.png)

2 - Gradle build + clean (app level)

[gradle app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP4pn.png)

3 - Choose app on the top bar (left of Run 'app')

4 - Clean Project:

Navigate to Build > Clean Project

And it should work now! You shouldn't disable instant run if you follow these steps

Comment: Build > Clean Project. Sometimes this is enough but if you do all the other steps it will work for sure

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.4 Canary 8. The error doesn't go away if i do the same as you mentioned above. It still persists. If you have any suggestions as to what may be the issue please revert.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Instant Run hided the real cause of the problem which was INSUFFICIENT_SPACE due to small data partition and I also got "failed to establish session" error.  After disabling Instant Run, the real problem was revealed and after fixing it and enabling Instant Run it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Allow or enable "Installation from USB" in the developer options.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in MAC(or may be other operating systems) can also be solved with this
You need disable "Use libusb backend" in preferences--> debugger

[image]

Please tell others if this was useful for you.
Thanks to the following user and their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58095554/3726185

Answer (score 0):

Go to USB Debugging and disable MIUI Inspection and allow the phone to reboot. Things should be fine from here

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to close the emulator and then select cold boot when re-opening it.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything else in this post, I would do  **Build >> Clean Project**. It solved my problem and it is the simplest solution. Sometimes, the cleaning doesnt get some links, so I also recommend you to restart your devices, either virtual or physical.

If it doesnt work out, try turning of **Instant Run** by **File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check**

Only after trying this two simple solutions, I would try the others.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the in-built emulator and kept encountering this problem.

To fix it:

- Go to: Run > Edit Configurations
- Click your device in the dropdown near "Preferred Android Virtual Device" and press Shift + Enter
- Close the config screen, and focus the new window with the AVDs.
- On the emulator you use choose the menu option on the right, and choose "stop" and "wipe data".
- For good measure: Build > Clean Project

Some of this might be unnecessary but I can't replicate the problem deliberately in order to trial a minimum amount of steps

Answer (score 0):

For those, who still having troubles with APK installing, just check your phone storage.
In my case app failed to install always because I had not enough space to install the APK.

Answer (score 0):

·clean project——that's what I consider first, but not work

·disable instant run——no this option in latest version

·turn off MIUI optimization——I don't use MIUI emulator

·Build apk, gradle....——no no no

You know what? When I **uninstall the app in my emulator**, and run the code again, it works as immediately!

Comment: in my case: settings->disable libusb