# Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting an error message while trying to run an apk through android studio 3.4 canary 1.

Gradle plugin version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01`

```
Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 526049657 with command cmd package install-commit 526049657.. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

I have tried uninstalling the apk, restarting android studio and the device and invalidating caches and rebuilding but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with android studio 3.4 canary 1, I reverted to 3.3 beta 1 and everything works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem and found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695197

Answer (score 30):

I disabled "Instant Run" in settings, and it works for me.(Android Studio 3.4 canary)

[image: picture]

Then you can see the adb command executed in the terminal is "adb push", while it is "adb install-multiple" before that is disabled.

Comment: This also solves others commit install session error like `pm install-commit` and `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK` error code.

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my life. I simply don't understand why even Google launched this feature if it is not stable. Leading to time wastage of Android devs. Phew.

Comment: This worked for me today with a clean install of 3.4. Thank you!

Comment: @Jude Fernandes This does seem to be a solution (worked for me). You should try it and possibly selected it as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 15):

On Android studio go to build menu : 
[Build menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xNr1.png)

Then:

> 1. First Clean
> 2. Rebuild
> 3. run it again

*******It works well **********

Comment: After performing the above 3 steps, It didn't work until I restarted my system!

Answer (score 11):

1. build->clean project
2. rebuild project
3. Delete as shown below

[image]

Comment: Deleted the app/build directory alone and then run. It works fine for me.

Comment: Just doing "build->clean project" did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Disable "Instant Run".

File->Setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Instant Run-> unCheck (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy)

and Run your Project and after that go and Enable Instant Run to use the advantages of Instant Run

Comment: I face this problem again,tnx myself:))))

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of the APK installed on a device/emulator and you create a new version of the APK that compiles against an SDK above the device/emulator sdk, you get this error vs. the original "yo, you are targeting 28 and this device has 26... come one, you need a 28 device/emulator".

You have to actually turn off instant run to see the right error.

Why would you do this? Good question! I mixed up my Q vs P devices and wasted an hour trying to figure out what was going on. :P

Answer (score 0):

Most easy solution is, wipe data of your emulator and run project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed this problem by getting rid of the meta data section in my manifest. I have no clue how it was added to the manifest to begin with (I'm a noob), but once I removed it from the manifest, the app loaded right up.

<Activity

...

/>

remove the meta data line within the manifest and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

> **Build** > **Clean Project**
>
> **File** > **Invalidate Caches & Restart**

Answer (score 0):

Just checked In AndroidMainfest file is not complaining any issue.
I have updated targetSDK version 33 and it required "android:export" flag in activity section