# Flutter: The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

Tags: android, flutter

My Android phone is customized. I created an empty Flutter project and found that the Flutter does not run on this Android phone. The mobile system version is as follows:

[image]

The following error message is displayed：

```
01/10 10:38:10: Launching 'app' on vivo V2036A.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/gengyibin/untitled1/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 965055649 with command 
cmd package install-commit 965055649. Error: 
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION'
Retry
```

My flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale
zh-Hans-CN)
• Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/gengyibin/Documents/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 18116933e7 (3 months ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
• Engine revision d3ea636dc5
• Dart version 2.14.4
• Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
• Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/gengyibin/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
  Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter


• No issues found!
```

Comment: check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53684398/16585144

Comment: I tried to do so, the Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch (4) Instant Run corresponding is HotSwap, but is still the same error

Comment: @keyur [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptVRA.jpg)

Comment: Which OS version your device has ?

Comment: @HardikMehta vivo Y30 Funtouch OS_10.5 Android 10

Comment: is there same app already installed on device ?

Comment: No, I just created an empty Flutter project to run on the real machine. It works fine on other phones, only this one or this type of phone can't be installed. Now I'm not sure if it's the Flutter problem or the individual phone system

Answer (score 0):

Build the app, then try to run it. It may solve the problem.

Comment: I tried Rebuild, but the problem still exists

Comment: flutter build apk --reelease

Then install manually the apk to your phone, and check it.

Comment: Thanks in advance.I tried it according to your suggestion, and the mobile phone reported an abnormal application installation (-102).[Install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW5RY.jpg) I tried to search the error code -102, but no useful information was found

Comment: I think there is some problem in your android - manifest. Will you please post the manifest here?

Comment: Sure, but I created an empty Flutter project and everything is default[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7guge.jpg),I suspect it's a system problem with custom phones, but I'm not entirely sure