# Android Studio Application Installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes when I go to build and test my apps I get this error and it drives me off the wall. I never had to deal with this before.

```
 Installation Failure
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: 'cmd package install-create -r -t --full  -S 2816556' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'
```

I tried following this guide here 
[Application Installation Failed in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687607/application-installation-failed-in-android-studio)

I did all the suggestions disable instant run, build apk then rebuild app, restart computer, restart android studio, use different virtual device.

Idk anymore any ideas? I am using Android Studio 3.4.1

Update: Fixed it my issue sorta. If i first launch my virtual device and get it loaded. Then run my app the error doesn't pop up. This leads me to believe that Android Studio will throw the installation error because it can't run the app on the virtual device since it takes forever to load on my laptop