# Failed to install-write all apks samsung GT-I9500

Tags: android, android-studio

```
defaultConfig {
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.orbizpro.lboard"
        minSdkVersion 17                     
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.20190904"
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        //
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

> 12/23 12:29:36: Launching 'app' on samsung GT-I9500. Installation did
>   not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation
>   failed due to: 'Failed to install-write all apks' Retry

Comment: You can disable Instant Run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687607/application-installation-failed-in-android-studio/54203116

Comment: @ProtiucAndrei instent run is not available in latest android studio

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message several times:

> List of apks: [0]
> 'C:\Users\jorgesys\git\JorgesysPuisorIoana\build\outputs\apk\debug\puisor-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: 'Failed to install-write all apks'

I had the same app installed with a previous VersionCode, but this app had a different certificate, you have to delete your installed app then install the new one.

You can also restart your device and try again to upload your app.